# Batch loop not performing as expected

Tags: loops, batch-file, goto

I'm writing a script to start up a system via IPMI. One of the machines must be reachable before bringing up the other machines.

I wrote a simple loop expecting it to work, but it's giving me some troubles

```
:PING_LOOP
ping -n 1 -w 1000 <IP Address>
IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 GOTO PING_LOOP
```

Where `<IP Address>` is the ip address of the machine I need to wait for before continuing. The loop works for like 3 or 4 iterations, but then fails after that even though the system isn't reachable yet. Is there a reason for this?

EDIT: This script is being run from a Win Server 2008 R2 machine

Comment: just tried on my machine with an unreachable ip (128.10.0.2), the loop works

Comment: interesting. win server 2008 r2?

Comment: tried on windows 7 x64 and 2008 r2 x64

Comment: what's got me confused is that it loops a few times before it gives a false reading. immediately after it fails i manually ping it and it's still getting an `ERRORLEVEL` of 1

Comment: @Franklin I've tried it on XP (all I have available) and it works fine, both for a non-existent host-name and IP address. Have you tried printing out `%ERRORLEVEL%` each time to determine what the value is (maybe the server *is* briefly available)? Also, have you tried writing the test as `IF ERRORLEVEL 1`, as per [Raymond Chen's suggestion](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2008/09/26/8965755.aspx)? It shouldn't make a difference, but there might be some other code you have not posted that means it would make a difference...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright figured it out.

Apparently when you `ping` something and you get `Destination host unreachable` it produces an `ERRORLEVEL` of `0` even though you aren't getting a ping, which doesn't make sense to me. Maybe I just don't completely understand how `ping` works

Here is a quick fix, though. I just parse out TTL. It's a bit naive, but it works for my application.

```
:PING_LOOP
ping -n 1 -w 1000 <IP Address> | find "TTL"
IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 GOTO PING_LOOP
```

Comment: Naïve or not, [my observations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5037382/batch-file-loop-ping-output-to-file-hosts-that-are-up/5039117#5039117 "Batch file - loop ping - output to file hosts that are up") were identical to yours and I haven't found other solution so far.