# Batch Script to find out whether a host is up or down

Tags: windows, batch-file

I need to scan several systems in the network within IP range 172.18.x.x to 172.25.x.x and check whether each of them is active or not, and then dump the result in a file.
Following is the script:

```
@echo off
for /L %%x in (18,1,25) do (
    for /L %%y in (1,1,254) do (
        for /L %%z in (1,1,254) do (

    ping -n 1 172.%x.%y.%z | find "Reply" > NUL
    IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 (set state=UP) ELSE (set state=DOWN)

    echo 172.%%x.%%y.%%z is %state% >> state.txt
)))
```

But, the result concludes that every system is 'UP' even though some IP addresses are unused.

Any problem with the script?

Comment: Seems to be working fine on my system after replacing **ping -n 1 172.%x.%y.%z** with **ping -n 1 172.%%x.%%y.%%z** in the script. No other change done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. The standard `delayedexpansion` problem. Many, many, many, many examples here on SO about this.

Within a block statement `(a parenthesised series of statements)`, the **entire** block is parsed and **then** executed. Any `%var%` within the block will be replaced by that variable's value **at the time the block is parsed** - before the block is executed - the same thing applies to a `FOR ... DO (block)`.

Hence, `IF (something) else (somethingelse)` will be executed using the values of `%variables%` at the time the `IF` is encountered.

Two common ways to overcome this are 1) to use `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` and use `!var!` in place of `%var%` to access the changed value of `var` or 2) to call a subroutine to perform further processing using the changed values.

Further, because your batch neither resets `state` when it terminates nor uses a `setlocal` to automatically clear changes to the environment on termination, on subsequent running, the previously-set value of `state` is used (hence the very first time, you'd get `echo is off` and thereafter the state of the last server scanned)

```
IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 (set state=UP) ELSE (set state=DOWN)
```

Oh! the fuzzy thinking here - and it's becoming prevalent, not just common. What's wrong with

```
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (set state=DOWN) ELSE (set state=UP)
```

which is far more straight-forward and doesn't involve double-negatives?

Solution 1:

```dos
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /L %%x in (18,1,25) do (
    for /L %%y in (1,1,254) do (
        for /L %%z in (1,1,254) do (

    ping -n 1 172.%%x.%%y.%%z | find "Reply" > NUL
    IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (set state=DOWN) ELSE (set state=UP)

    echo 172.%%x.%%y.%%z is !state! >> state.txt
)))
```

Solution 2:

```dos
@echo off
for /L %%x in (18,1,25) do (
    for /L %%y in (1,1,254) do (
        for /L %%z in (1,1,254) do (

    ping -n 1 172.%%x.%%y.%%z | find "Reply" > NUL
    (
    IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (echo 172.%%x.%%y.%%z is DOWN
     ) ELSE (echo 172.%%x.%%y.%%z is UP
    )
    )>> state.txt
)))
```

Comment: @Magoo - Should I replace "Reply" with "TTL"?
It is creating problem when the result is-"Reply from x.x.x.x: Destination Host is Unreachable"

Comment: @MandarShinde : Yes - make that replacement. I'd assumed that the test you were applying made the distinction - the apparently-unchanging report of the value of `state` was my concern.

Answer (score 0):

Ping returns an errorlevel by itself these days:

```
@echo off
for /L %%x in (18,1,25) do (
    for /L %%y in (1,1,254) do (
        for /L %%z in (1,1,254) do (

ping -n 1 172.%%x.%%y.%%z > NUL
IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 (
       >> state.txt echo 172.%%x.%%y.%%z is UP
   ) else ( 
       >> state.txt echo 172.%%x.%%y.%%z is DOWN
)

)))
```

Comment: [Errorlevel=0 may not always indicate the host is up](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5039117).

Comment: @AndriyM  Thanks for that - if the router responds with the error message in your link then you don't have connectivity and everything will fail, is that right?

Comment: Yes, that's my understanding. I myself have only experienced this when pinging a missing/non-existent host *within the local network*. (I mean, just pinging some arbitrary 192.168.1.123 that doesn't exist, the 192.168.1.* being my network.)